# Tor.real and problems restarting Tor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, help, mac

I was surfing and the Tor Browser suddenly closed. Now when I restart it (latest version 5.0.4 Mac) it gives me a screen to **Restart Tor** and at bottom of page are **Quit**, **Copy Tor Log to Clipboard**, and **Continue** buttons.
I've tried to paste the log into an email message but nothing has been copied to Clipboard. **When Restart Tor** is clicked, it simply refreshes the same page.After several attempts at that I get a small box saying **Tor Launcher** not successful.
When click **Continue** nothing happens.
Anyway, checked Activity Monitor which told me that a file or process called **tor.real** has been running constantly since this trouble started. When the computer is awake, this process runs even though Tor Browser is off. What's going on?
Please help..
Steve

I've also tried to reinstall it, but same thing.

Answer (score 2):

tor.real is the actual Tor process.

Normally, Tor Browser starts 'tor.real' on launch and kills it again when you quit the browser. When your Tor Browser crashed, it didn't kill tor.real. Now when you start Tor Browser, it tries to start tor.real, but it can't because one is already running.

The solution is to manually kill tor.real either from activity monitor or in a terminal. After that, you should be able to launch Tor Browser again.

(The same thing happened to me once while updating the Tor Browser.)